# Get all metadata of a file apache tika TikaJAXRS

Tags: java, python, jax-rs, apache-tika, tika-server

Hi i deployed https://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS to a server and 
when i upload a file and call `/meta`  i get the response below for  a docx file

> u'{"Content-Encoding":"UTF-16LE","Content-Type":"application/json;
>   charset\u003dUTF-16LE","X-Parsed-By":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser","org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],"language":"bn"}')

1.File language is english but tika returns 'bn'?

2.Is this the only meta data that i will get? how about file owner etc?

The Code:
     i use python

```
body= open('/home/Desktop/aws/0.docx','rb')
files = {'upload_file': body}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'}
r = requests.put('http://xx.xx/meta',
                  files=files,headers=headers)
print('text',r.text)
```

Comment: Are you sure that's a real docx file, and not a plain text file renamed as `.docx` ?

Comment: yea pretty sure, amazingly it work ok if i use curl

Comment: I'd double check your Python then, as you must not be sending the actual content. BTW there's a Tika Python wrapper that might handle this all for you